# umlauts-domain in magento e-mail validation?

Tags: magento

is there a way to allow umlauts-domains for e-mail addresses in Magento? when entering such domain at the moment, there's an validation error. where can i find those validation settings?

thanks in advance!

Comment: are you sure related with magento? Maybe your server doesn't recognize non-latin characters!

Comment: also, did you try IDN coded email address? for instance, oğuz.com equivalent xn--ouz-hsa.com

Comment: as with the umlaut, the server doesn't take IDN urls...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you'll need to change at least the appropriate Prototype and Zend validators to achieve this.

Scan `js/prototype/validation.js` for the pattern `'validate-email'` to find the client-side validation part.

To locate the server-side validation part search the pattern `Zend_Validate_EmailAddress` in the file `app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Attribute/Data/Abstract.php`.